# Connecting frontend to backend in MERN stack application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am working on an Exercise tracker application using MERN stack. I am facing an error and I am not being able to render it.
`create-user.componet.js` file:-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
const axios=require('axios');

 class CreateUser extends Component {
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);

        this.onChangeUsername=this.onChangeUsername.bind(this);//even binding
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);//event binding


        this.state={
            username: '',
            
        }
    }
    onChangeUsername(e) {
        this.setState({
          username: e.target.value
        })
      }
      onSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault() //prevents from default process and implements the lined following

        const user={
            username: this.state.username
           
        };
        console.log(user)

        //connecting the front end to the backend. On submit the username will be stored in the backend.This is done by using axios
        axios.post('http://localhost:3000/users/add',user)//accesses the route mentioned in user.js and hence connecting to the backend
        .then(res=> {
            console.log(res)
            console.log(res.data)});
        
        this.setState({
          username: ''
      })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>Create New User</h3>
                <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                    <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Username: </label>
                <input  type="text"
                         required
                         className="form-control"
                         value={this.state.username}
                         onChange={this.onChangeUsername}/>
                        
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" value="Create User" className="btn btn-primary">
                        </input>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default CreateUser
```

route fie:-

```
    const router=require('express').Router();
let User=require('../models/user.model')

router.route('/').get((req,res) => {
    User.find()
    .then(users => res.json(users))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error:'+err))

});
router.post('/add', function(req, res)  {
    const username = req.body.username;
  
    const newUser = new User({username});
  
    newUser.save()
      .then(() => res.json('User added!'))
      .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
  });
module.exports=router;
```

error:

`POST http://localhost:3000/users/add 404 (Not Found)`

On implementing the application the above error is being showed, whereas the api is working fine when tested in insomnia(tool).

Could someone help to render this issue?

Comment: `router.route('/')`  your problem is here. it should be `router.get('/', (req, res) => { .... })`  .route() is used in the file that is including the router, not by the router itself. (Unless you are forwarding to another router, but forwaring '/' first is just senseless, because it skips everything else in the router.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are targeting the wrong route,

in your server you have

```
router.post('/add', function(req, res)
```

But in the client you target

```
axios.post('http://localhost:3000/users/add',user)
```

Try changing it to

```
axios.post('http://localhost:3000/add',user)
```

Or try changing the server to

```
router.post('/users/add', function(req, res)
```

Comment: But it's a router, this is normal. Somewhere else there is a `app.use('/users', router);` I'd still love to see that file though....

Comment: Can you try going to `https://localhost:3000/add` and `https://localhost:3000/users/add`?

Comment: If you are defining `app.use('/users', router);` It would be great if you could add that to the code, since we cannot know that :)

Comment: I am defining app.use('/users',router); in the server.js file